# How do I get the data from HostedFeatureLayer for todays date using python from ArcGIS Online

Tags: python, arcgis

The following code pulls data using `sdfinsp` from **`arcgis`**

```py
feature_layer_id = ' '
Inspform = gis.content.get(feature_layer_id)
insp = Inspform.layers[0].query().sdfinsp.to_sql('testtable',con=engine,schema=None,if_exists='replace',index=False,index_label=None,dtype=None,method=None)
```

The featurelayer has two fields with create date and edit date.  would like to pull data where createdate or edit date is equal to sysdate.

Answer (score 1):

Use datetime format for SQL like `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'`.  So, effectively your syntax would be:

```sql
feature_layer_id = ' '
Inspform = gis.content.get(feature_layer_id) 
insp = Inspform.layers[0].query(where="CreationDate > '2022-04-12T00:00:00.000'").sdf
insp.to_sql('testtable',con=engine,schema=None,if_exists='replace',index=False,index_label=None,dtype=None,method=None)
```

Your syntax for datetime comment, from gis stackexchange.

**Edit:**

For variables:

```sql
insp = Inspform.layers[0].query(where="CONVERT(datetime, CreationDate, 21) > CONVERT(datetime, sysdate, 21)").sdf
```

Note that 21 here is the date time format code for exact representation desired, like this '2022-10-07 17:46:00.158999808'.

Comment: How do we write the syntax without hard coding the date. It should be based on sysdate. CreationDate format is 2022-10-07 17:46:00.158999808

Comment: insp = Inspform.layers[0].query(where="CONVERT(datetime, CreationDate, 21) > CONVERT(datetime, sysdate, 21)").sdf                                                              
gave an error:          Exception: 
'where' parameter is invalid
(Error Code: 400)                                                                                                                                          Also, looks like the comparison is in sql, i am looking in python. Please post any resources if you have any

Comment: You can use `datetime` library in python for better conversions.